# Masonry in magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript

does any body have idea that how to include masonry in magento 2? 
as i added requirejs-config.js  them in masonry i used require on the top of the code then i added this code in bottom of list.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        requirejs( [ 'require', 'jquery', 'masonry' ],
            function( require, $, Masonry ) {
// require jquery-bridget, it's included in masonry.pkgd.js
                require( [ 'jquery-bridget/jquery-bridget' ],
                    function( jQueryBridget ) {
                        // make Masonry a jQuery plugin
                        jQueryBridget( 'masonry', Masonry, $ );
                        // now you can use $().masonry()
                        $('.grid').masonry({
                            // your settings
                        });
                    }
                );
            });
    </script>
```

but i am getting this error continuously.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/afSEo.jpg

Answer (score 0):

> `$` seems undefined it means `jquery` not added in deps.

Change the code like below:

```
require(['jquery', 'masonry', 'jquery-bridget/jquery-bridget'],
    function( $, Masonry, jQueryBridget ) {
        // make Masonry a jQuery plugin
        jQueryBridget( 'masonry', Masonry, $ );
        // now you can use $().masonry()
        $('.grid').masonry({
            // your settings
        });
    }
);
```

I hope it will helps.

Comment: i think i have added the jquery in above code?

Comment: yeah but its seems undefined in `require jquery-bridget`

Comment: what is bridget? could you please specify your answer in detail? and where i use the above code?

Comment: after adding above code, http://prntscr.com/mzhts1

Comment: in above screenshot error shows on custom.js? can you share your custom js?

Comment: here is custom.js http://prntscr.com/mzi1qt